# Do not hardcode "/sdcard/"; media storage change?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

as of right now I am using this:

```
String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
               String filename=soundname+".ogg";

               boolean exists = (new File(path)).exists();
               if (!exists){new File(path).mkdirs();}

               FileOutputStream save;
               try {
               save = new FileOutputStream(path+filename);
               save.write(buffer);
               save.flush();
               save.close();
               } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               return false;
               } catch (IOException e) {
               // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               return false;
               }

               sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"+path+filename)));

               File k = new File(path, filename);

               ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
               values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, k.getAbsolutePath());
               values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, soundname);
               values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/ogg");
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, "...");
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
               values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

               //Insert it into the database
              this.getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(k.getAbsolutePath()), values);


              String i = "Saved as Ringtone.";
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), i,
               Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

             return true;


              }
```

But eclipse says that I should be using:

```
Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()
```

I tried just adding it, but now it won't save, and I am not sure what to do. Can anyone help me implement this please?

Comment: Same Warning in Android Studio and I originally had tried it that way.  
On an HTC M8 /sdcard/ works fine (like everywhere) but using the "official" storage path not.  
I can store there but other apps have no access (email attachments, etc)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It doesn't matter.

But you can add this line:

```
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
```

above

```
String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
```

**(or)** just change

```
String path="/sdcard/media/audio/ringtones/";
```

to:

```
String path=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/media/audio/ringtones/";
```

Comment: @CRUSADER yes, i meant that

Answer (score 1):

You can avoid that by suppressing it:

```
@SuppressLint("SdCardPath")
```

but you should use `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()`

Like

```
String PathToSdcard = Evironment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/media/audio/ringtone"
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to use `Environment` because you cannot be sure that external storage path is `"/sdcard/"`. Try using

```
File dir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_RINGTONES)
```

And then some refactoring:

```
if (!dir.exists()) dir.mkdirs();
File file = new File(dir, filename);
save = new FileOutputStream(file);
```